# Count of items in aggregated column in Athena

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have some columns as listed below:

| FirstName | Fruits | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sean Doe | Oranges | 2022-06-03 |
| Jon Doe | Apples | 2022-06-02 |
| Jon Doe | Mangoes | 2022-06-02 |
| Sean Doe | Peaches | 2022-06-02 |
| Jon Doe | Strawberries | 2022-06-02 |
| Sean Doe | Blueberries | 2022-06-02 |
| Jon Doe | Blueberries | 2022-06-01 |

I'm looking for a query that would give me following output in Presto/ AWS Athena

| FirstName | aggregated_fruits | Date | count_of_fruits_on_one_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jon Doe | Apples,Mangoes,Strawberries | 2022-06-02 | 3 |
| Jon Doe | Blueberries | 2022-06-01 | 1 |
| Sean Doe | Peaches,Blueberries | 2022-06-02 | 2 |
| Sean Doe | Oranges | 2022-06-03 | 1 |

My incorrect current query is returning this:

```sql
Select
    FirstName,
    Date,
    array_join(array_agg("Fruits"), ',') AS aggregated_fruits , 
    count(*) AS count_of_fruits_on_one_date 
FROM FruitTable
WHERE <condition> 
GROUP BY FirstName, Fruits, Date 
ORDER by count DESC;
```

| FirstName | aggregated_fruits | Date | count_of_fruits_on_one_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jon Doe | Mangoes,Mangoes,Mangoes | 2022-06-02 | 3 |
| Jon Doe | Apples, Apples | 2022-06-02 | 2 |
| Sean Doe | Oranges | 2022-06-03 | 1 |

Comment: TBH seems to be pretty straightforward one. What have you tried and what is not working for you?

Comment: edited the post to reflect whats not working. I am bit of a novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query contains one extra grouping - by `Fruits`. Remove it:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(FirstName, Fruits, Date) AS (
    VALUES ('Sean Doe'  , 'Oranges' ,'2022-06-03'),
        ('Jon Doe'  , 'Apples'  ,'2022-06-02'),
        ('Jon Doe'  , 'Mangoes' ,'2022-06-02'),
        ('Sean Doe' , 'Peaches' ,'2022-06-02'),
        ('Jon Doe'  , 'Strawberries'    ,'2022-06-02'),
        ('Sean Doe' , 'Blueberries' ,'2022-06-02'),
        ('Jon Doe'  , 'Blueberries' ,'2022-06-01')
)

-- query
Select
    FirstName,
    Date,
    array_join(array_agg(Fruits), ',') AS aggregated_fruits , 
    count(Fruits) AS count_of_fruits_on_one_date 
FROM dataset
GROUP BY FirstName, Date 
ORDER BY count(Fruits) desc
```

Output:

| FirstName | Date | aggregated_fruits | count_of_fruits_on_one_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jon Doe | 2022-06-02 | Apples,Mangoes,Strawberries | 3 |
| Sean Doe | 2022-06-02 | Peaches,Blueberries | 2 |
| Sean Doe | 2022-06-03 | Oranges | 1 |
| Jon Doe | 2022-06-01 | Blueberries | 1 |